# How do I use SQL LIKE '%value%' operator with Azure Functions SQL Binding?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions

With the Preview version of the Azure Function [SQL Input Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-input?tabs=csharp), you can easily execute SQL queries by specifying it in the binding, e.g.:

```cs
 [FunctionName("GetToDoItem")]
 public static IActionResult Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "gettodoitem")]
   HttpRequest req,
   [Sql("select [Id], [order], [title], [url], [completed] from dbo.ToDo where Id = @Id",
     CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
     Parameters = "@Id={Query.id}",
     ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
     IEnumerable<ToDoItem> toDoItem)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(toDoItem.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    ...
```

As soon as I try to use the LIKE Operator like e.g.:

```cs
 [FunctionName("GetToDoItem")]
 public static IActionResult Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "gettodoitem")]
   HttpRequest req,
   [Sql("select [Id], [order], [title], [url], [completed] from dbo.ToDo where Id = @Id and title like '%Stackoverflow%'",
     CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
     Parameters = "@Id={Query.id}",
     ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
     IEnumerable<ToDoItem> toDoItem)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(toDoItem.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    ...
```

I'm getting an exception as follows:

`Error indexing method 'GetToDoItem' '%Stackoverflow%' does not resolve to a value.`

I understand, that this is due to the [app setting lookup of the binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings), but I can't figure out a way to kind of "escape" these percentage signs. Currently, my only workaround is to execute the query manually.

Is there any other option to use the percentage sign for SQL like comparisons?
I've tried a double %% sign as well as escaping the % with a backslash.

Comment: Just wondering if you could pass `%Stackoverflow%` as part of parameters. Something like `Parameters = "@Id={Query.id},@Title='%StackOverflow%'"` and then modify the binding like `[Sql("select [Id], [order], [title], [url], [completed] from dbo.ToDo where Id = @Id and title like @Title"`.

Comment: As a workaround you could use CHARINDEX instead of LIKE. You then don't require any percent characters in the string. But performance will be worse in the case you don't want a leading wildcard. Or you could use CHAR(37) in the SQL rather than a literal percent. But hopefully there is a syntax to escape these anyway!

Comment: @GauravMantri unfortunately that didn't solved the issue, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @MartinSmith this works, thanks! Nevertheless, I also hope a more convenient syntax will be available in future versions.

Comment: Hello @DSpirit, If any of the above answers helped you, could you please post it as an answer with some explanation so that it will be helpful to other community members!

Comment: Ah damn, didnt think of @MartinSmith solution. I ended up changing it to using EntityFramework. Honestly, EF saved a ton of time on other bits. This isn't about answering the question directly, but if someone wants to overcome this kind of issue Dapper/EF etc ORM would be helpful. Though sql binding could be tricky when using these but possible; as you can manipulate the bound sql and then run it as raw sql with EF/Dapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workaround solution.

If it turns out that there is a syntax to escape percent characters then this will be rendered immediately obsolete.

But one way of avoiding the issue will be to change the query as below

```
SELECT [Id],
       [order],
       [title],
       [url],
       [completed]
FROM   dbo.ToDo
WHERE  Id = @Id
       AND title LIKE Concat(Char(37), 'Stackoverflow', Char(37))
```

This should get constant folded (in the SQL Server execution plan) to

```
title like '%Stackoverflow%'
```

without including any literal `%` in the actual query string.